# Why in oracle jobs log sometime the value in last star Date is bigger than Next run date

Tags: oracle

Why is the last start date sometimes bigger than the next run dat in the Oracle jobs log?

When you select values in the `ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS` table:

```
select * from ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS
```

Sometimes the last start date is bigger than the next run date. For example, the last start date is:

> 2015/08/11 16:20:00.155707 +08:00

and next run date is:

> 2015/08/11 16:20:00.000000 +08:00

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

It means that the job is now running and the new value for the next run will be set after the current run finishes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.